# Barchart reorder using ggplot not working properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mrlfnh6e2ww1xwd/home.csv?dl=0

Here is my code:

```
hom <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
home.melt <- melt(hom, id.vars='home')

ggplot(home.melt, 
aes(x = reorder(home, value), y = value, 
fill=forcats::fct_rev(variable))) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.8) + coord_flip() +
theme_minimal(base_size=10) +
labs(title="Home time",
   subtitle="By matches",
   x="Home",
   y="time (minutes)",
   fill=" ")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see it's not ordered in descending manner.

Comment: Reorder axis or fill?

Comment: Cloud storage links are discouraged because they tend to break over time.

Comment: Reordering the bars according to the total time. 'St' should be on top, then 'Ln' and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is specifying the function in the call to reorder:

```
reorder(home, value, FUN = sum)
```

the default is "mean"

```
 ggplot(home.melt, 
               aes(x = reorder(home, value, FUN = sum), y = value, 
                   fill=forcats::fct_rev(variable))) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.8) + coord_flip() +
          theme_minimal(base_size=10) +
          labs(title="Home time",
               subtitle="By matches",
               x="Home",
               y="time (minutes)",
               fill=" ")
```

Comment: Done sir! Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

hom <- fread("home.csv")
home.melt <- melt(hom, "home")
home.melt[, variable := factor(variable, levels = sort(unique(variable), decreasing = TRUE))]

ggplot(home.melt, aes(home, value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.8) + 
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = home.melt[, sum(value), home][order(V1), home]) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
    labs(title = "Home time",
         subtitle = "By matches",
         x = "Home",
         y = "Time (minutes)",
         fill = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this is not is descending order. 'St' should be on top, then 'Ln' and so on.

Comment: Almost! Only thing is that if you see my original chart, you'd notice that a1,a2,a3,...b7 are stacked in certain order, i,e., a1 is closest to y-axis and b7 is farthest from y-axis. I'd like to maintain that in addition to what your code does.